# Linking files having multiple main function in c

Tags: c, linker, makefile

Is it possible to link two C files using makefile which calls each other function but both have a `main` function of their own.

e.g:
 C1.c uses function `f()` from C2.c.but both have `main` function and I want the `main` in C1.c to be considered as `main` only.

```
FILES.o=set.o hash.o printnfa.o input.o nfa.o dfa.o terp.o minimize.o defnext.o print_ar.o pairs.o squash.o signon.o print.o lex.o assort.o prnt.o printv.o bintoasc.o ferr.o onferr.o fputstr.o pchar.o driver.o searchenv.o hashadd.o esc.o 

PROGRAM= Lexer
INC := -I./debug.h -I./global.h -I./stack.h -I./set.h -I./hash.h
CFLAGS=-DMAIN
all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} $(INC) $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

Now terp.c has a `main` and lex.c also has a `main`. I want only the `main` for lex.c to be considered.

Comment: You could add a preprocessor condition around the `main` in one file, or you will get a linker error (multiple definition of `main`).

Comment: Ya thats present in the terp.c file

Answer (score 3):

This will be specific for the linker you use. On Linux you can pass the `--allow-multiple-definition` flag to the linker in order to use only the first symbol in case of multiple definitions:

```
${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
${CC} -Xlinker --allow-multiple-definition -o $@ ${CFLAGS} $(INC) $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

This will omit all errors about duplicate symbols and cause the linker to ignore any redefinitions. Make sure that the object file containing the symbol you wish to use comes before any redefinitions in the list.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--allow-mutilple-definition'..This is what they are showing

Comment: @Paku As I said it will depend on your linker. Check `man ld` if you can find a similar option.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer... NO ... it is NOT possible

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would recommend that you refactor the code so that you don't have functions that will be used by many programs in the same file as a main function.

Any way, here is an example on how to use the pre-processor to include only one of the main functions.

We have two source code files both with a main function plus one other function, foo() in file1.c and bar() in file2.c. foo() and baa() are called from both of the main functions.

By changing the MAIN_ALT value in the Makefile we can switch between the main functions:

Use the main function in file1.c:

```
DEFINES += -DMAIN_ALT=1
```

Use the main function in file2.c:

```
DEFINES += -DMAIN_ALT=2
```

#### Makefile:

```
OBJS = file1.o file2.o
DEFINES += -DMAIN_ALT=1
CFLAGS += -Wall $(DEFINES)
prog:$(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

#### file1.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "def.h"

void foo(){
    printf("From foo\n");
}

#if MAIN_ALT == 1
int main(){
    printf("Main in file1.c\n");
    bar();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

#### file2.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "def.h"

void bar(){
    printf("From bar\n");
}

#if MAIN_ALT == 2
int main(){
    printf("Main in file2.c\n");
    bar();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

#### def.h:

```
#ifndef __DEF_H__
#define __DEF_H__
void foo();
void bar();
#endif
```