# C99: Call main function from another 'main'?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213829/calling-main-function-from-another-function-in-c) has a similar title but we are discussing different things.

Say I want to invoke the `main` of a code foo.c

```
int main(){
   ...
}
```

The problem is that the caller is another `main` routine, and it seems impossible to have two `main` functions.

How can I call `foo.c`'s main function from another `main`?

The name of the `main` in foo.c **cannot be changed**, because it is not a user-code.

Comment: Why do you have two main functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665187/linking-files-having-multiple-main-function-in-c

Answered here.

Comment: [`exec()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html)?

Comment: @Kay. Yeah, sort of. I have edited my question above.  Not possible to change the name 'main' in foo.c.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth One main is from a third part program; another one is mine.  Imagine you write an application that displays "Hello World" and your program is in 'main', and I want to use your program. What can I do?

Comment: @zell which environnment ? Linux, Windows, ... ?

Comment: @zell Maybe you should tell us what exactly you want to achieve from the user's (not the programmer's) standpoint.

Comment: You say that `main` is from foo.c, but can't be changed. So you don't really have foo.c, or else you'd change it. So tell us what you really have. Do you have an object file? A library (shared or static)? An executable? Be specific.

Comment: Well, name your own entry function 'myMain()' or something, and bodge the crt library to call it instead of main().

Comment: @James. Would you make it more clear --- what do you mean by 'bodge the crt library'?

Comment: Well, somewhere you should have a 'crt.c' source file that contains the code to set up the C runtime environment - heap etc, and then, somewhere near the end, jumps to or calls main().  If you edit the crt to call myMain() instead, you should be able to rebuild crt and your app so that myMain() gets called as the C entry point.  You can then call the other main() whenever you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation you are describing sounds something like this:

```
/**
 * bar.c
 */
...
int main( void )
{
  ...
  // call foo.c's main function directly
  main( );
  ...
}

/**
 * foo.c
 */
int main( void )
{
  ...
}
```

You can't do that. There's no way to build a program that has two `main` functions defined.

So the question becomes, what are you really trying to do here?

1. Are `bar.c` and `foo.c` meant to be built into the *same* executable, with code in `bar.c` calling code defined within `foo.c`, while still allowing `foo.c` to be built as a standalone program?  If so, then you'll have to take that code out of `foo.c`'s `main` function and put it in a separate function, and you'll have to use some preprocessor magic to suppress `foo.c`'s `main` definition when both files are built together, something like this:

   ```
   /**
    * bar.c
    */
   #include "foo.h"
   ...
   int main( void )
   {
     ...
     foo_func(); // function defined in foo.c
     ...
   }

   /**
    * foo.h
    */
   #ifndef FOO_H
   #define FOO_H

   void foo_func( void );
   #endif

   /**
    * foo.c
    */
   #include "foo.h"

   void foo_func( void )
   {
     ...
   }

   #ifndef EXTERNAL_DRIVER
   int main( void )
   {
     ...
     foo_func();
     ...
   }
   #endif
   ```

   This allows `foo` to be built as a standalone program, as well as part of a larger program.  To build it as part of a larger program, you must define the `EXTERNAL_DRIVER` macro, something like this:

   ```
   gcc -o bar bar.c foo.c -DEXTERNAL_DRIVER
   ```

   Are `bar.c` and `foo.c` meant to be built into two separate executables, and have a running `bar` instance start a new `foo` instance, then wait for the `foo` instance to finish running before moving on?  If so, then you can use the C standard library's `system` function to invoke `foo` from `bar`:

   ```
   system("foo");
   ```

   although you may have to specify the path as part of the command, such as

   ```
   system("./foo")
   ```

   or

   ```
   system("/some/absolute/path/name/foo");
   ```

   If you're on a *nix system, you can use a combination of `fork` and one of the `exec*` functions to do much the same thing, except that the `bar` instance doesn't *have* to wait for `foo` to finish executing.  

   If you want the two programs to share data while running, then you'll have to look into various interprocess communication techniques (shared memory, sockets, pipes, etc.).

   . Are `bar.c` and `foo.c` meant to be built into two separate executables, and have a running `bar` instance execute code defined within a running `foo` instance?  That's a remote procedure call, which I've done maybe once in the last 20 years and, like interprocess communication, is a bit involved for a SO answer.

If I haven't covered your particular use case, let me know.

Answer (score 8):

> and it seems impossible to have two 'main' functions.

You can't have two symbol with the same name in the same object (binary, shared lib)...

At the end of the compilation, the compiler merges all `objects files` into into your target, resolving the symbol by name. It has no way to tell apart your two `main`s if they have the same name.

Rename one of the functions (the one which isn't the real entry point of the program).

**EDIT:** If you can't touch the other's main name from the code, change it after compiling. Exemple with gcc:

```
gcc -o other_main.o -c other_main.c
objcopy --prefix-symbols=foo_ other_main.o
gcc -o yourbinary other_main.o main.c
```

Then, call `foo_main` instead of `main` in your *real* `main`.

Comment: No. It does not work. The true entry point is from my program. The 'main' from foo.c is another guy's program that I can not touch.

Comment: @zell Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank. I will try it today. Could you explain  "objcopy --prefix-symbols=foo_ other_main.o"?

Answer (score 4):

You can rename the `main()` function like that:

```
objcopy --redefine-sym main=that_other_main obj1.o obj2.o
```

Where `obj.o` contains the `main()` that you don't want to be the main entry point of your program. You can then call it with `that_other_main(argc, argv)`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I call foo.c's `main` function from another `main`? There is one constraint here. The name of the main in foo.c cannot be changed, because it is not a user-code.

You cannot have two `main` functions in a program.

You cannot call the `main` of foo.c from another function since `main` is the starting point of a program as far as user code is concerned.

What you are trying to accomplish can be achieved only by having two different programs and executing the program that contains the `main` of foo.c from the other program using [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) or any of the [`exec***`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) family of functions.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is call the other program with a "`system('otherprog.exe arg1 arg2')"` call. That is if you don't care about the output going straight to stdout.

If you want to capture the output from the second program than you need to open a pipe with the more complex popen() call.

```
FILE *fp;
int status;
char res[MAXLINE];


fp = popen("otherprog.exe param1 parm2", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;

while (fgets(res, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL) {
    /* capture each stdout line from otherprog.exe */
    printf("do something with %s", res);
}

status = pclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to have two main's in one program

Answer (score 0):

you can't work with two main functions.You better change the function name from 'main' to any other in foo.c and call it.I think it will not change the ultimate result of your program.

Comment: Please only add a new answer if it adds new information.